# Implement search bar like in play store app

Tags: android

I want to add a search bar functionality top at the action bar like in Play Store app.

EditText should be expanded on click of the search button

How can I achieve this ?

Sorry if my question doesn't show any research effort, however i googled it & didn't find any result.

Thanks in advance

Comment: where you want to put serach option..use autocomplete tetxview

Comment: What functionality? Autocomplete or search view itself? Please add more details.

Comment: at the top in Action bar

Comment: you are looking for SearchView see this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView

Comment: @QadirHussain This has to be posted as an answer and should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 4):

Here what I found https://github.com/Quinny898/PersistentSearch. Voice recognition is also available.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is called **[Action View](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView)**. It allows you to embed widgets into the action bar, and the widgets will substitute the action button when you click it.

Here is the Google's tutorial on how to embed **[SearchView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SearchView.html)** into an action bar: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#UsingSearchWidget